# Sums and Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I want some help, please, to solve this problem.
Let $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,\ S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$
I want to prove that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,\ S_n\leqslant\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}$
and that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,\ S_n\geqslant2\sqrt{n+1}-2$

I used the **Mathematical Induction** method, so for $n=1$ we have : $S_1=1$ and $\sqrt{1-1}+\sqrt{1}=1$
Then the statement in this case is satisfied. Next we assume another real non-null number $k/\ S_k\leqslant\sqrt{k-1}+\sqrt{k}$ , and we prove that $S_{k+1}\leqslant\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}$ , but I'm stuck.

So please help me if you can.
Thanks!

Comment: The left hand side changes by $1/\sqrt{k+1}$. The right hand side changes by $\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k-1}$. If you can show the change of the left hand side is no greater than the change of the right hand side, you're done.

Comment: Yes, I reached that part, but I couldn't figure out how I can prove that $\sqrt{k-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\leqslant\sqrt{n+1}$

Comment: One way is to "rationalise the numerator" of $\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k-1}$. Another way is to multiply through with $\sqrt{k+1}$, then you must show $1 \leqslant \sqrt{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k-1})$. A little manipulation shows that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$S_{k+1}=S_k+\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\stackrel{?}\le \sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}$$

which is true indeed

$$S_k+\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\le \sqrt{k-1}+\sqrt{k}+\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\le \sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}$$

since

$$\sqrt{k-1}+\sqrt{k}+\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\le \sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}\iff \sqrt{k-1}+\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\le \sqrt{k+1}$$

$$\sqrt{k^2-1}+1\le k+1 \iff \sqrt{k^2-1}\le k \iff k^2-1 \le k^2 \iff -1\le 0$$

---

**Edit**

We also need to prove that

$$S_{k+1}=S_k+\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\stackrel{?}\ge 2\sqrt{k+2}-2$$

which is true indeed

$$S_k+\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\ge 2\sqrt{k+1}-2+\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\ge  2\sqrt{k+2}-2$$

since

$$2\sqrt{k+1}-2+\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\ge  2\sqrt{k+2}-2\iff 2\sqrt{k+1}+\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\ge  2\sqrt{k+2}$$

$$2(k+1)+1\ge  2\sqrt{(k+2)(k+1)} \iff 2k+3 \ge  2\sqrt{(k+2)(k+1)}$$

$$4k^2+12k+9 \ge 4k^2+12k+8 \iff 1\ge 0$$

Comment: Thanks! I think this is a good proof.

Comment: @Anonymous You are welcome! Bye

Comment: Can you tell me please how can I prove that $2\sqrt{n+1}-2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\geq 2\sqrt{n+2}-2$ ?

Comment: @Anonymous I add also something on that.

Comment: Now I realized how dumb I am. Well thanks, sir!